# System call open()

Tags: c, system-calls

im trying to get the contents of a txt file with system calls, but when my program calls the open() function again , the buffer gets strange data.

```
void delFunction(){
int BUF_SIZE=8192;
int line=0,cont=0,x=0,y=0;
char buf[BUF_SIZE];
char buf2[BUF_SIZE];
char buf3[BUF_SIZE];
fflush(stdin);
int filedesc = open("testfile.txt", O_RDONLY);
read(filedesc, &buf, BUF_SIZE);
close(filedesc);
printf("BUFFER: \n");
puts(buf);
printf("Choose the line you want delete\n");
scanf("%d",&line);

for(x=0;x<strlen(buf);x++){
    if(line==cont){
    }else{
        buf2[y]=buf[x];
        y++;`
    }
    if(buf[x]=='\n'){
        puts(buf2);
        cont++;
    }
}
int filedesc2 = open("testfile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC);
write(filedesc2,buf2, strlen(buf2));
close(filedesc2);
buf2[0]='\0';
```

}

At the 1st time the program runs well, but at the 2nd time the buffer gets the .txt content plus wrong data

Comment: `read()` will not null-terminate your buffer for you. You don't check the return value of *any* of your system calls.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the read manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html):

> Upon successful completion, read() [XSI] [Option Start]  and pread() [Option End] shall return a non-negative integer indicating the number of bytes actually read.

... you need to use the return value to determine how many bytes were actually read (and you probably shouldn't be using an ampersand before `buf` here).

eg. `ssize_t how_many_bytes = read(filedesc, buf, BUF_SIZE);`

`puts` doesn't let you specify `how_many_bytes`, so perhaps you'd be better off using `fwrite`.

eg. `fwrite(buf, 1, how_many_bytes, stdout);`

Similarly, [the scanf manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html) tells you how to use the return value of scanf:

> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number of successfully matched and assigned input items; this number can be zero in the event of an early matching failure. If the input ends before the first matching failure or conversion, EOF shall be returned. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set, EOF shall be returned, [CX] [Option Start]  and errno shall be set to indicate the error. [Option End]

eg. `if (scanf("%d", &line) != 1) { exit(0); }`

[**Don't flush stdin**](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html)...